# Is it possible to restart a series of scheduled emails from a membership that has lapsed and then resurrected?

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

We have setup a series of 9 scheduled reminder emails to be sent out monthly after signup to a membership. ie, 1 month after membership start, 2 months after, 3 months after, etc.

There are occasions when the membership slips out of good standing for a few periods, and then comes back into good standing. Either because of admin errors, or non-payment and then re-subscription.

When the membership slips out of good standing, the series of scheduled reminders being sent to the contact is stopped. That's good!

But when the membership comes back into good standing, the series of scheduled reminders doesn't seem to continue or restart... or anything.

So questions:

1. Is it possible to cause them to start up again? Or even better, is it possible to get them to start from a particular point in the series of scheduled reminders?
2. Also, are the queued emails stored in the database from the start of the membership? Or are they generated on the fly when the reminders' date conditions are fulfilled? If they are stored in the db I haven't found them... I have found sent ones in civicrm_action_log.

We're on 4.6.21, Drupal 7.52. Thanks for your thoughts!